# Need help removing rust from hinge

Tags: rust

I have a handicapped van with a side conversion ramp. The hinge attached to the floor of the van has considerable rust and since I live in Ohio we have harsh winters. So what would be the best way to remove the rust that is forming on the hinge. Picture are below.

I have done research, and I had found out that Kroil Penetrating Oil with a brass brush should do the trick. However I have never done anything like this and was wondering if I could get some advice please? Also what could I use to stop the rust from coming back?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: I would just give a regular oiling. It doesn’t look too bad and doesn’t look like it needs wire brushing.

Comment: I always use Ospho....http://www.ospho.com/

Answer (score 1):

This hinge does not look like it has enough rust to cause a functional issue. I recommend just oiling it well (light machine oil will do fine, like 3-in-1).

If you don't like the way it *looks* with the rust then go ahead and wire brush it. Dry brush it until it looks the way you want, then use a shop vacuum to clean up the rust/dust. Then thoroughly oil it and keep it oiled to prevent future rust.

Answer (score 0):

The metal rusts to get back to its natural state. Protect with proper preparation then primer, base and top coat or equivalent. In harsh conditions then an enamel paint or a two-pack epoxy paint also works well.

High temperature paint is meant to work well... But I painted two exhaust manifolds where the nice black finish was gone after 1 trip...

Comment: The problem with "primer, base and top coat or equivalent" is, you put it into the hinge and it will no longer work. The paint will cause it to stick and bind, therefor no longer behaving like a hinge. Yes, it will stop the rust, but it will also stop the hinge from functioning.

Comment: There are many painted hinges and hinges with other finishes... If you put paint on with a yard broom then it goes everywhere....

Comment: Even if you paint it with a 000 art brush, it will still get in the hinge and cause it not to work like it should. Yes, rust will stop it just as sure, but without putting paint in the hinge, you're not going to stop the rust within it.

Comment: Unless you submerge the hinge in a fluid treatment how do you guarantee 100% coverage?